# CUPS disconnects after update to 16.04

Tags: printing

I got a newly updated 16.04 Lubuntu from 15.10.

As stated in the title, I can't stay connected to the localhost CUPS server, clicking Home->System Tools->Printers.

The "Start Service" button is greyed out, and "Connect"ing to localhost returns the error `failed to connect to server`.

"Troubleshooting" directs me to look for `System->Administration->Services` to look for a cups service. I don't see such an option in the Start menu.

`cups is already the newest version (2.1.3-4).`

I'm lost to what I'm supposed to do, but I'm researching what to do still.

It'd be nice if you could guide me through what to look for.

UPDATE:

`sudo apt-get install cups --reinstall` **did the trick for a while**, but after running a program that was looking for the default printer (JavaFX), the connection disappeared.

Seeing as doing it a second time did the trick again, I'll leave this question for enterpretation. I'll update more if I get in trouble again.

Question title edited to reflect findings.

UPDATE

Confirmed. Although reinstalling it does fix it, using my program that *only checks for a default printer* caused it to disconnect. I do not know why this is so. There might be a separate cause.

UPDATE

Possible [duplicate](https://askubuntu.com/questions/898173/unable-to-print-system-settings-printers-says-that-cups-is-not-running-but-s?rq=1), but his solution didn't work. It still disconnected after a few minutes.

UPDATE

Tried restarting the service. `sudo service cups restart` Still disconnects/stops after some time. **Might be a better alternative to the re-install**. Answer edited.

Answer (score 0):

Out of curiousity, I decided to just restart CUPS

`sudo service cups restart`

Works. Well, might as well share to everyone.

**NOTE**: Read question update for why this is a temporary fix.

Comment: `Cups` has always been erratic in terms of working (for me). Since the printer does not seem to be affected and I can communicate directly with the printer through a local webage, I have been ignoring `cups` periodic failure to connect.